# Virus that affects only males?

Tags: humans, zombies, sex, gender, viruses

Furrious Rabies affects only males in this universe, in our real universe it affects both genders.
in our real universe I've never heard of any virus that only affects people with Y chromies.

So I'm just asking if it's possible and realistic or I should just handwave it away?

Why of the question? Zombies... it's always zombies, and maybe Vampires too...

Comment: It is hard for a virus to target only carriers of a Y chromosome, because the Y chromosome does not code for anything much other than "this individual ought to be a male". (If you think about it, this is to be expected -- after all, half the population lives perfectly well without a Y chromosome, so that it is obviously nothing important coded on it.)

Comment: @AlexP ehm but could females carry the virus and be unaffected? so both genders can be infected but only one get's the consequences?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. If your worldbuilding problem is different from the one marked as duplicate, please make the difference visible.

Comment: I've gotta admit... it is always zombies....